# AHK: Find text and Replace all

Tags: autohotkey

How do I replace the letters ve at the end of each word with the letters on. Please see the picture:[I know that this word is not correct but it is an example only to clarify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKejn.png)
Such a code sentence:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
F2::
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^+{End}
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait
    Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "^(.*?)i(.*)", "$1o$2")
    Send, ^v
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "^(.*?)i(.*)", "$1o$2")
```

with

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "ve\b", "on")
```

The \b makes it match only the "ve" at the end of words, for example, it will change "vetvetve" to "vetveton"
Note that RegExReplace is case sensitive (it will not change "VETVETVE"), to make it case-insensitive use the i) option:

```
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "i)ve\b", "on")
```

Comment: It's a great job thank you so much, I learned something different
Please allow me this question:
- What if I want to replace two letters in the center of the word:
Example: Replace characters (ve) in a word (Prevents) with (x) letter

- What if I want to replace two characters at the beginning of the word:
For example: Replace (re) in the word (return) with (u) letter

Comment: \b marks the start and end of the word

Replace characters (ve) in a word:
 `Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\b(.*)ve(.*)\b", "$1on$2")`

replace two characters at the beginning of the word:
 `Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\b(.*)re(.*)\b", "$1u$2")`

Comment: correvtion: replace two characters at the beginning of the word: `Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\bre", "u")`

Comment: Welcome and hello Mr. Yane:
I reiterate my thanks and appreciation to you for this useful and distinguished lesson

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this one. You can instead use a simple string replace

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
F2::
    Clipboard := ""
    Send, ^+{End}
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait
    Clipboard := StrReplace(Clipboard, "ve", "on")
    Send, ^v
return
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But it replaces the two letters (ve) in any location of the word and not just at the end of the word.